# I'm trying to run a SQL procedure while creating my sql_stmt at runtime. I get hung up when trying to execute the sql_statement in for x in ()

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I need to create my sql statement on the fly, because for this scheduled procedure my table partition will change every day.  I have tried this a couple different ways, and I can't figure out how to run my sqlstmt variable inside 'for x in ()'

If the sqlstmt needs to be it's own function or procedure, that's fine.

Thanks,

So this is a very dumbed down version of what I am trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P1 AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    L_BODY VARCHAR2 (32767);
    V_SECONDS VARCHAR2 (6);
    V_SQLSTMT VARCHAR2 (4000);

V_SQLSTMT := 'SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''SSSSS'') TSTAMP  FROM TABLENAME PARTITION(P' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMMDD') || ')';

BEGIN 
    V_SECONDS := '0';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<h3>CHECK LAST RECORD </h3>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TABLE BORDER=1 BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR BGCOLOR="BLACK">';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TH><FONT COLOR="WHITE">TABLE</FONT></TH>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TH><FONT COLOR="WHITE">TIME STAMP</FONT></TH>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '</TR>';

FOR OUTPUT IN (
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQLSTMT
)

LOOP
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR>';
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD> OUTPUT FROM NAME </TD>';
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD>' || to_char(trunc(OUTPUT.tstamp/3600),'FM9900')||':'||to_char(trunc(mod(OUTPUT.tstamp,3600)/60),'FM00')||':'||to_char(mod(OUTPUT.tstamp,60),'FM00') || '</TD>';
V_SECONDS := V_SECONDS + OUTPUT.TSTAMP;
END LOOP;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI''';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set smtp_out_server=''IP.IP.IP.IP:25''';

IF V_SECONDS < 86370
THEN
UTL_MAIL.SEND (      
     I'M NOT TYPING ALL THIS OUT
);
END IF;
END;
END P1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a dynamic query with that cursor loop; you need to open, fetch and close the cursor:

```
DECLARE
    ...
    L_TSTAMP VARCHAR2(5);
    OUTPUT SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN 
    V_SQLSTMT := 'SELECT TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''SSSSS'') TSTAMP  FROM TABLENAME PARTITION(P' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMMDD') || ')';
    V_SECONDS := '0';
    ...
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '</TR>';

OPEN OUTPUT FOR V_SQLSTMT;
LOOP
 FETCH OUTPUT INTO L_TSTAMP;
 EXIT WHEN OUTPUT%NOTFOUND;
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR>';
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD> OUTPUT FROM NAME </TD>';
 L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD>' || to_char(trunc(L_TSTAMP/3600),'FM9900')||':'||to_char(trunc(mod(L_TSTAMP,3600)/60),'FM00')||':'||to_char(mod(L_TSTAMP,60),'FM00') || '</TD>';
V_SECONDS := V_SECONDS + L_TSTAMP;
END LOOP;
CLOSE OUTPUT;
...
```

Not sure why you have V_SECONDS as a string, or why you're using TO_CHAR in your query. You could keep the seconds counter as a number, and get the display value formatted as a second select list item. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to show though, and as you've said this is a dumbed-down version things might be different in your real code.

Since, as you pointed out, your query can only return one row, you don't need a cursor loop at all, just a dynamic `select ... into`:

```
DECLARE
    L_BODY VARCHAR2 (32767);
    V_SECONDS NUMBER;
    V_SQLSTMT VARCHAR2 (200);
    L_SECONDS NUMBER; BEGIN 
    V_SQLSTMT := 'SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''SSSSS'')) FROM TABLENAME PARTITION(P' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMMDD') || ')';
    V_SECONDS := 0;
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<h3>CHECK LAST RECORD </h3>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TABLE BORDER=1 BGCOLOR="#EEEEEE">';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR BGCOLOR="BLACK">';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TH><FONT COLOR="WHITE">TABLE</FONT></TH>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TH><FONT COLOR="WHITE">TIME STAMP</FONT></TH>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '</TR>';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQLSTMT INTO L_SECONDS;
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD> OUTPUT FROM NAME </TD>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD>' || to_char(trunc(L_SECONDS/3600),'FM9900')||':'||to_char(trunc(mod(L_SECONDS,3600)/60),'FM00')||':'||to_char(mod(L_SECONDS,60),'FM00') || '</TD>';
    V_SECONDS := V_SECONDS + L_SECONDS;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''DD-MON-YYYY:HH24:MI''';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter session set smtp_out_server=''IP.IP.IP.IP:25''';

    IF V_SECONDS < 86370
    THEN ...
```

(I changed the data types to numbers because they were bugging me *8-)

You could also get the formatted time as a string from your query, instead of having to recreate it from the seconds value:

```
DECLARE
...
    L_SECONDS NUMBER;
    L_TIME VARCHAR2(8);
BEGIN 
    V_SQLSTMT := 'SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''SSSSS'')), TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''HH24:MI:SS'') FROM TABLENAME PARTITION(P' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE-1,'YYYYMMDD') || ')';
    V_SECONDS := 0;
...
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQLSTMT INTO L_SECONDS, L_TIME;
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TR>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD> OUTPUT FROM NAME </TD>';
    L_BODY := L_BODY || '<TD>' || L_TIME || '</TD>';
    V_SECONDS := V_SECONDS + L_SECONDS;
...
```

Comment: Alex - Does the V_SQLSTMT always have to go into a SYS_REFCURSOR?  Or could I have put the V_SQLSTMT results directly into a variable since this particular query would only return 1 row?  I am asking because oracle docs was saying the SYS_REFCURSOR is for multi row queries.    I tried fetching directly into a var, but oracle says I have to do a fetch into a cursor.  Thanks

Comment: @magicJerk - right, I didn't notice that you had a single-row query. So no, you don't need a cursor at all. Updated with a demo. What data type and value do you have in `time`? You can probably do that output formatting in the query too.

Comment: In the table it is a date field, if pull it without to_char it returns 17-APR-15.  But since I need the time (and since I am doing math) I use -SSSSS to pull out the time.

Comment: AH, there is my mistake... I tried to do a "select TO_CHAR(MAX(TIME), ''SSSSS'') into L_tstamp from.." in my V_SQLSTMT, rather than after the execute immediate  Thanks dude!

Comment: and since I am already storing the seconds in L_SECONDS, I won't be needing V_SECONDS anymore either.  Much cleaner

Comment: @magicJerk - yes, the `into` clause is outside the dynamic text. I've added a version that gets the formatted time in the query too, just for fun.